# tcpdump doesn't appear to be capturing any data, why?

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I'm trying to capture data with `tcpdump` like so:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -Xi eth0
```

I have the device and the PC connected to each other. On both sides I launch a simple test application that sends a message to the other.

The problem is that although both sides get the messages, `tcpdump` didn't print anything. Only an ARP requests sometimes is seen *(an ARP requests for another PC which is not currently connected to the LAN)*.

```
$  ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:ea:62:ce:d6  
          inet addr:10.5.57.197  Bcast:10.5.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:eaff:fe62:ced6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66497 errors:0 dropped:4334 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6539170 (6.5 MB)  TX bytes:553828 (553.8 KB)
          Interrupt:21 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:71721 (71.7 KB)  TX bytes:71721 (71.7 KB)
```

Comment: Can you show that your app is listening on either 0.0.0.0 or specifically on the IP above? Use `netstat -tapn` and look for the port that it's listening on to confirm.

Comment: It seems like a network problem. Can you please show the other machine ifconfig too?

Comment: @Fale, no, it wasn't the network problem, it is a problem with the «tcpdump», see my comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you capture the packets and write them to a file with the `<file>.pcap` extension, and then open with `wireshark`.

For example, in CentOS, to capture the packets:

```
$ tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1500 -w /root/<filename.pcap>
```

Comment: Hmm… I have no idea why, but the «tcpdump» prints a packets only with the `-w` option. Your answer is the correct.

Comment: Use -n with tcpdump to stop it trying to resolve IP addresses to names, which can take a long time.

Comment: @wurtel yeah! Now it works! So this was the problem!

Comment: @vallikkv can one captures the packets on the link-local interface ?

Answer (score 2):

Something else must be up. The following test works fine for me. I'm using `socat` as both the client and server and I'm running `tcpdump` on my local system that I'm sitting at.

#### 1. Setup socat server (listener)

```
$ socat - TCP-LISTEN:2222,crlf
```

#### 2. Setup socat client

```
$ socat - TCP:192.168.1.80:2222
```

#### 3. Now I run tcpdump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -Xi wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.3
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp1s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:04:27.977900 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.149 tell client.mydom.net, length 46
    0x0000:  0001 0800 0604 0001 0019 d1e8 4c95 c0a8  ............L...
    0x0010:  0103 0000 0000 0000 c0a8 0195 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
10:04:29.206642 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.149 tell client.mydom.net, length 46
    0x0000:  0001 0800 0604 0001 0019 d1e8 4c95 c0a8  ............L...
    0x0010:  0103 0000 0000 0000 c0a8 0195 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
10:04:29.337077 IP client.mydom.net.49878 > server.mydom.net.EtherNet/IP-1: Flags [P.], seq 1391164406:1391164421, ack 2721007444, win 46, options [nop,nop,TS val 535977938 ecr 956529523], length 15
    0x0000:  4500 0043 8218 4000 4006 34f9 c0a8 0103  E..C..@.@.4.....
    0x0010:  c0a8 0150 c2d6 08ae 52eb 7bf6 a22f 4754  ...P....R.{../GT
    0x0020:  8018 002e 964f 0000 0101 080a 1ff2 5fd2  .....O........_.
    0x0030:  3903 7b73 5468 6973 2069 7320 6120 7465  9.{sThis.is.a.te
    0x0040:  7374 0a                                  st.
```

In the above scenario I typed the message "This is a test" on the client side and it showed up on the server's `socat` instance as well as within the output of `tcpdump`.

*Client output:*

```
$ socat - TCP:server.mydom.net:2222
This is a test
```

*Server output:*

```
$ socat - TCP-LISTEN:2222,crlf
This is a test
```

Comment: The «tcpdump» start capture a packets only with the `-w` option. I don't know why, but that is.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - Can you do a `sudo strace -s 2000 -o tcpdump_strace.log tcpdump -Xi eth0`? Something is inhibiting `tcpdump` from performing. It's likely something in your environment, would be my guess.

Comment: @wurtel [just told the real reason](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155869/tcpdump-doesnt-appear-to-be-capturing-any-data-why/155879?noredirect=1#comment254953_155873).

Comment: @Hi-Angel - yeah you should either write that up as an A or have wurtel do it. The one you marked isn't really the appropriate A to your issue, IMO.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - the `strace` I suggested would've bared this out BTW 8-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this one another good answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130911/tcpdump-localhost-to-localhost, if the traffic that isn't showing up is localhost->localhost traffic. I feel like in other situations I haven't had to do that, but at least a few times I've had to.

Comment: You could also do `sudo tcpdump -i any`, thus capturing from all existing interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by wurtel:
Use `-n` with `tcpdump` to stop it trying to resolve IP addresses to names, which can take a long time and result this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo bash
```

and then

```
tcpdump ...
```

On some Linux versions I see this from time to time that tcpdump or similar tools don't work with sudo as expected..